# What is the difference b/w (long long int)1 << j and 1 << j in cpp

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

first code:

```
void solve() {
  unsigned long long int l, r;
  cin >> l >> r;
  unsigned long long int ans = l ^ r;
  for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ((ans >> i) & 1) {
      for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        ans = (ans | (1 << j));
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  cout << ans << '\n';
}
```

Second code:

```
void solve() {
  unsigned long long int l, r;
  cin >> l >> r;
  unsigned long long int ans = l ^ r;
  for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ((ans >> i) & 1) {
      for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        ans = (ans | ((long long int)1 << j));
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  cout << ans << '\n';
}
```

The first code gives wrong answer for 1000000000 2000000000 and second gives right answer.

Comment: What is the right answer and what is the wrong answer? Both examples give the same result: https://godbolt.org/z/fGEesTea5 The correct solution would be `1ull << j` to already start with the correct type and have no overflow.

Comment: The value `1` is a plain `int`. And `int` on most systems is only 32 bits. Attempting to shift more bits than available for the type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: if you to want a variable of a particular type use the `int32_t`, and `uint64_t` and the rest for different sizes, then you are compiler independent

Answer (score 1):

```
1 << j
```

will result in an `int`, so maximum of 32 bits accuracy. if `j` is above 31, the result is undefined, since the result is bigger than what a 32 bit integer can hold. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined, — the possible manifestations of such an operation include:
>
> - it wraps around according to the rules of the representation (typically 2's complement),
> - it traps — on some platforms or due to compiler options (e.g. -ftrapv in GCC and Clang),
> - it saturates to minimal or maximal value (on many DSPs),
> - it is completely optimized out by the compiler.

Also if `j` is 31, the result will be negative because the signed bit will be overwritten.

---

```
(long long int)1 << j)
```

the result will be a 64 bit signed integer, and since `j` is never bigger than 62, the result is well defined.

Comment: `1ull << j` is a little cleaner to write.

Comment: well they were asking for the difference.
true, `ll` in this case is more direct and the`unsigned` version would be even more appropriate.

Comment: C++ doesn't define the max number of bits in an `int`. That's implementation-specific. </pedantry>

Comment: Note that "max of 32 bits accuracy" is a common implementation, but not required. An `int` has to be at least 16 bits, and there is no upper limit on its size.